# How soon can my non-EU spouse re-enter the EU after a 90-day stay?

Tags: us-citizens, schengen, eu-spouses

I am a dual citizen, EU and US. My husband is a US citizen and retired. We will be in the EU together for 90 days. A month later, my husband would like to re-enter the EU and stay for another two months.

Is he able to re-enter after so short a time? Would he be able to re-enter if I were to go with him? If we re-enter together, would he be able to stay in the EU without me?

Comment: Will you be in the Schengen area?  If, for example, you are in the UK for 90 days then there will be no trouble for him to enter a Schengen country.  Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: We, together, will be in a Schengen area, (Now changed) for 120 days. He would like to leave after 120 days and then return to a Schengen area two months later after having left the Schengen area. Alternatively he would like to stay for another two months but without me.

Answer (score 1):

First, a couple of points:

- Legally speaking, your husband enjoys freedom of movement in the EU only when he accompanies you there or is traveling to join you.
- In calculating the time in the Schengen area for the 90-days-in-180 rule, there's no provision for excluding days that are spent in the area in the company of an EU-citizen family member.

So, while your husband can remain in the the Schengen area *with you* for longer than 90 days, he is nonetheless using up days for the purpose of calculating how long he can stay there *without you.*  This means that if you leave after spending 85 days there together, he should leave within the next five days.  If you stay for 90 or more days together, he should leave when you leave.  If he leaves with you after 120 days and tries to return two months later, he will not have been outside the Schengen area for long enough, and he is liable to be refused entry.

However, the freedom-of-movement directive allows countries to require non-EU family members to get a residence card if they are staying for more than 90 days, and most countries do this.  If he does get a residence card, his days will not count against the 90/180 rule, because periods of stay under a residence permit or long-stay visa are excluded from that calculation.  If he can get a residence card, therefore, he ought to be able to stay for two months after you leave, or to return two months later for a two-month stay.

The problem, of course, is that it may not be possible to get the residence card in 120 days.  You haven't said which country you'll be in; I am most familiar with the situation in France, and from what I've heard, it can take quite a bit longer than 4 months for the card actually to be issued.  From your comments, it appears that you want to stay in Italy; perhaps you can ask another question here about the time required to get one.

Comment: We are going to study in Italy. If he gets a student visa for 4 months would that time count towards the 90 days? Could he go back after the four months to do a hike that will take 6 weeks?

Comment: @Tricia If he gets a student visa, that time will not count towards the 90 days.  However, he's likely to be refused a student visa if he is coming with you on the grounds that he does not need one. The residence card for the spouse of an EEA national should be easier to get and probably cheaper, and getting one within four months may be possible in Italy; I don't know. If he doesn't have a visa or residence card, though, he can remain outside the Schengen area for at least 90 days to reset the 90/180 counter, so if he stays away for four months he can return (without you) for a six-week hike.